# How to print or store all skipped lines of a large log file in logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-file

Some times due incorrect pattern of some lines of logs inside complete log files are skipped by logstash.

It only sends all lines having pattern matched to grok syntax i have written.

I want to see which lines of logs are skipped or not read by logstash so that we can make that pattern correct.

I have added

```
output {

if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {

stdout { 

codec => rubydebug

}

}

else

 {
 }
 }
```

but it only prints the grok parse failure for lines read by logstash

So how to print or store all skipped lines in a output log file .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a output inside the `else` block, it is empty so logstash has nothing to do when the tag `_grokparsefailure` is not present.

Try something like this:

```
output {
    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        file { 
            path => "/tmp/grok-failed.log"
        }      
    } else {
        file { 
            path => "/tmp/grok-correct.log"
        }      
    }
}
```

This will save both messages to different files.